# Is it possible to add row number in mongodb document while saving it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I want to add `rowNumber` field to my documents that I save in MongoDB collection i.e. the first saved document will have `rowNumber` 1, second one will have 2 and so on.
I know this is possible by first querying total number of documents in collection and then saving the document with `rowNumber = count + 1`, but this involves two queries.

Is there a way to do this with a single query? My main concern with this two step approach is that of a race condition between two document writes which might lead to two docs with same `rowNumber`?

Comment: no, not possible, but it's likely because you are trying to apply relational db patterns to non-relational database. Is having rowNumber an ultimate goal of your application, or is it only an instrument to achieve something?

Comment: It would be even a challenge in relational database, because of transaction (e.g. rollback) and others.

Comment: @AlexBlex I intend to save these docs in Firestore too which allows client side snapshot listeners. Firestore does not allow fetching documents at custom offset (which I need for pagination) so I plan to add rowNumbers in docs which will allow me to paginate properly.

Comment: yeah, cross-sync is hard to implement, and even harder to QA. Can you use ObjectID instead of the rowNumber? Otherwise I'd push it back to the solution architecture to reconsider choice of technologies and may be simplify the set up to have a single source of truth. E.g. Mongo is aggressively expanding their SaaS offering. They bought Realm few years ago to address exact this usecase.  Did you consider https://www.mongodb.com/atlas/app-services/device-sync ?  Or is it other way round -  the main Firestore with a mongo sidecar?